# jQuery function string

Tags: jquery, html

This isn't working:

```
function checkIt(String rep) {
         if (counter[$(rep).val()] == undefined) {
         count++;
         result = Math.round((count * 100 )/howMany);
         $('.percent').text(result);
         $('#perc_in').animate({'width': result+'%'}, 500);
         counter[$(this).val()] = 1;
         $('#counter').text(result);
         }
}
```

Like, at all... <_< I mean I think I am doing the function wrong.

Then inside the case statement I have this:

```
checkIt($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is weak typed, so what in the world is this?

```
function checkIt(String rep) {
```

Just change it to

```
function checkIt(rep) {
```

It's also a bit odd that you are try to create a new jQuery object from the value of another form element. And this line:

```
if (counter[$(rep).val()] == undefined) {
```

This may be a little dangerous if you're just checking for the non-existence of an array element, since `$(rep).val()` could also be undefined depending on the situation.

Comment: Also, it is unclear where `count` is defined, and what it is used for (if at all).

Comment: @karim Well, let's assume that all variables are declared. If not we could just as easily say that jQuery isn't properly load ;). As for uses erm... some sort of global count on how many times this function has been called?

Comment: @Yi Jiang - good point. Would be good to know, as it looks downright confusing :) I voted you up btw, that wasn't a 'gripe' but an innocuous (and I hoped useful) comment :)

Comment: OK that seems to work for only two of cases.... and I get undefnied when i do $(rep).val()...

Comment: @Dan Two possible reasons: 1. `rep` isn't a valid selector, so jQuery's returning undefined. 2. The element selected by `$(rep)` doesn't have a `value` attribute. Not that I didn't warn you on that in the answer...

Comment: It only works for the first two case uses and then it stops... so I'm going to see what I did wrong tomorrow or well it didn't work corerct in the first place but we shall see!

Comment: @Dan - It'd help if you posted all your code, since there seem be errors outside of the code currently posted.

Comment: index.php: http://www.xasad.pastebin.com/btPyt0Y8
theGame.js: http://www.xasad.pastebin.com/9z7UyKF2

Comment: You're right - it's somethign in that code. I stripped it of it's execssive code with just the bare bones and it worked fine.